# The use of OP's in a sentence in english stack exchange

Tags: sentence-meaning

I have come cross the use of OP's.What does OP's mean as used in a sentence.

Comment: That's a bit of forum jargon. OP stands for _Original Poster_. On Stack Exchange, that is the person that asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

On online forums, message boards, discussion spots etc., OP stands for Original Poster, the one who initiated the discussion. As an example, in this discussion, it is you, @Robert Motari Ontiri, who is the OP.